# How to run docker command in buildspec.yml of code commit in windows environment?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker

I am deploying the .NET application into the ECS Fargate cluster. I am doing this automation by CodePipeline. I choose the Windows environment in CodeBuild.
I ran the `docker build -t image-name .` command in my buildspec.yml file to build the Dockerfile to upload the image to ECR, but I am getting the below error:-

```
docker: The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
```

Can anyone suggest how I can use docker cmd with the Windows environment in Code Pipeline?